# Javascript map method - write key only if there is a defined value for it

Tags: javascript

I am using a map method in Javascript to convert an array of objects to an array of objects with different key names. Let's say I have an array like this:

```
let arr1 = [
{id:1,name:"Luke"},
{id:2},
{id:3,name:"Greg"},
{id:4,name:"Joe"}
]
```

So, one of the objects hasn't got the "name" key. If I map it like this:

```
let arr2 = arr1.map((data) => (
{
id2:data.id,
name2:data.name
}
))
```

it will give an output like this:

```
 [
{id2:1,name2:"Luke"},
{id2:2,name2:undefined},
{id2:3,name2:"Greg"},
{id2:4,name2:"Joe"}
]
```

My question is: is it possible not to write the key if the value is null/undefined? I want an output like this:

```
 [
{id2:1,name2:"Luke"},
{id2:2}, // ==> no name2 key bcz the value is undefined
{id2:3,name2:"Greg"},
{id2:4,name2:"Joe"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr1 = [
{id:1,name:"Luke"},
{id:2},
{id:3,name:"Greg"},
{id:4,name:"Joe"}
]
    let arr2 = arr1.map((data) => ({
        ...(data.id && { id2: data.id}),
        ...(data.name && { name2: data.name})
    }))

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach to this would be looping through the objects keys. This will work without any hard-coded keys, so any key could be missing and any additional keys will also be included:

```js
const arr1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Luke"
  },
  {
    id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Greg"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Joe"
  }
]

const arr2 = arr1.map((data) => {
  const newObj = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    newObj[`${key}2`] = value
  }
  return newObj
})

console.log(arr2)
```

This will only include existing keys, and they can be modified inside the template string here:

```
newObj[`${key}2`]
```

This could be expanded with e.g. a switch statement to match and replace specific names if required.

Comment: Why U complicate just simple things ?

Comment: @MarekLisiecki It's not particularly complex, this version just works with any missing keys. If all the asker wants is a one-off key that might be missing, your solution works. If they want to cover the general situation where any key might be missing in a potentially large object, my answer will handle that.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    {id:1,name:"Luke"},
    {id:2},
    {id:3,name:"Greg"},
    {id:4,name:"Joe"}
].map(i => ({
    id2: i.id,
    ...(i.name != undefined && {name2: i.name})
}))
```

or...

```
[
    {id:1,name:"Luke"},
    {id:2},
    {id:3,name:"Greg"},
    {id:4,name:"Joe"}
].map(i => ({
    id2: i.id,
    ...(i.name && {name2: i.name})
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the object with the `id` first, and then add the name if it exists.

```js
const arr1=[{id:1,name:"Luke"},{id:2},{id:3,name:"Greg"},{id:4,name:"Joe"}];

const arr2 = arr1.map(data => {
  const out = { id2: data.id };
  if (data.name) out.name2 = data.name;
  return out;
});

console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, something like this should do:

```
let arr2 = arr1.map(({id, name }) => (
    Object.assign(
        { id2: id }, 
        name ? { name2: name } : {},
)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just do something like below:

```js
let arr1 = [
{id:1,name:"Luke"},
{id:2},
{id:3,name:"Greg"},
{id:4,name:"Joe"}
]


let arr2 = arr1.map((item) => ({...item}));


console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: This is not aswer for @OmarLittle question

Comment: @MarekLisiecki Did you run the script?